Ubuntu reboot log question
I run an Ubuntu machine that is running 24.04 with Live Patch enabled for the kernel. My machine recently rebooted unexpectedly and came back online again at 11:09 AM. While looking at the logs to see the cause of this reboot, I came across few Live Patch related entries around 11:08 AM which would have been right before the machine rebooted.
Just out of curiosity, if anyone is expert in reading these logs please confirm if the reboot is related to a patch applied otherwise I may have to keep looking elsewhere.
https://pastebin.com/Gba4h0Ti
And here are other specs for reference:
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

Firmware details:
$sudo lshw | grep -A8 '*-firmware'
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 6232
          date: 09/29/2024
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi

About the motherboard:
$sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: PRIME X370-PRO
    Version: Rev X.0x
    Serial Number: 170296198105048
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

FYI, I've recently updated the BIOS.

Assuming your hardware is a enterprise grade server, have you looked in your machine logs (ie. hardware logs), as they often have clues (though if you looked and it reports as 'software reboot', then yes you need to look in the OS logs)

Thanks @guiverc. Good point, it could be a hardware issue. I'm running a gaming PC that bought on eBay and will update the post above with the hardware specs (for reference).

The log that you provided does not definitively indicate that the Canonical Live Patch Service was the cause of the reboot that came back online again at 11:09 AM. There are a few exceptions to kernel live patching which are listed in the accepted answer to Why do I have to reboot to activate a kernel upgrade even though live kernel updates are enabled?.
If your hardware is an enterprise grade server, try looking in your hardware logs for additional references to the reboot activity at 11:09 AM that was reported in the log that you provided.

Thanks. So live-patch does not seem to be the source of my problem of unexpected machine reboots. I'll keep monitoring when the next reboot happens (unexpectedly), I capture logs and post here. In the meantime, I've run 12 passes on memtest86+ and fsck checks on memories and hard disk and found no errors.
